# Error 100 XML Http Request fails in Parse with Phonegap iOS only

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, parsing, xmlhttprequest

The device is unable to send any request to Parse when I use Phonegap iOS verison only. It works fine with Phonegap Android and Web Browser. Gives error of 100 xmlhttprequest failed.

Comment: Is it related somehow with the other one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360244/xmlhttprequest-failed-on-app?noredirect=1#comment48834604_30360244

Comment: Thanks, i was able to solve it.