# XMLHttpRequest failed on App

Tags: cordova, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I'm trying to run a simple singup example on my mobile app using Ionic framework and Parse.com.
The code is simple as follows:

```
Parse.initialize(APP_KEY, JS_KEY);
Parse.User.signUp("my.user", "123456", {}, {
  success: function(user) {
    // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
    console.log('yuhuuu ' + user)
  },
  error: function(user, error) {
    // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

This code works when I test it on my browser, but when I run it on my cellphone I get an error code `100` with the following message:

[image]

I've tried already to change the way I singup (usin the object instead of passing user and password directly). Also checked if the android app has proper permissions for accessing web resources (it's OK).

Comment: Why don't you use pure javascript xhr ? I mean this both works in browser and app..

Comment: It's throring 404, page not found. You should check the URL being inboked

Comment: @BipBip The idea of using their API and Lib is to avoid this kind of hassle.

Comment: @TechMa9iac This is what seems strange to me. Why does it works on the browser and not when running in app? I'll try debugging inside their lib to see if the logic changes in both cases.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After digging a little deeper I've found this [link](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/crosswalk-and-http-doesnt-work/20275/18), which brought to my attention the root cause of my problem. Cordova (one of underlying platforms of Ionic) limits requests to only local (`file://`) resources, which made all external requests fail.

In order to overwrite this behaviour you need to use the [whitelist plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) and set it up to allow you desired api backend.

This can be achieved as follows.

First, add the plugin to the project.

```
 cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git
```

Then set up your backend to the whitelist at the `config.xml` file.

```
<allow-intent href="*://*api.parse.com/*"/>
```

Comment: I've spent all day at this issue, driving me insane. Just as I'm about to leave for the day I find your answer and I'm thinking, oh well, this is probably not gonna work but I'll give it a shot. IT WORKED! Thanks for taking the time to answer your own question and not just deleting it or leaving it unanswered.

Comment: and with capacitor same issue! What can I do?

Comment: Sorry @El7or , can you elaborate on what do you mean by "capacitor"?

Comment: @FabricioBuzeto Capacitor is a cross-platform app runtime that makes it easy to build web apps that run natively like cordova:
https://capacitor.ionicframework.com